# Как отключить менеджер автозаполнения гугл?

Tags: html, autocomplete

На сайте есть форма при клике на input гугл предлогает вставить данные[image: введите сюда описание изображения]. Можно ли это поведение убрать на сайте?

```js
$('input').on('focus',function(){
$(this).removeAttr('readonly');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="user_pass"  type="password" autocomplete="off" readonly="readonly" value="">
```

Вот мой input ни autocomplete="off" (пробывал разные вариации ничего не работает) ни readonly не помагают.
Вообще возможно отключить автозаполнение?

Comment: а в чем смысл убирать автозаполнение?

Comment: `onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly')"`

Comment: Оно мешает. 
Вы написал код по сути что у меня